# Limiting the number of characters in a string, and chopping off the rest

Tags: java, string, substring

I need to create a summary table at the end of a log with some values that 
are obtained inside a class. The table needs to be printed in fixed-width 
format. I have the code to do this already, but I need to limit Strings, 
doubles and ints to a fixed-width size that is hard-coded in the code.

So, suppose I want to print a fixed-width table with

```
    int,string,double,string
    int,string,double,string
    int,string,double,string
    int,string,double,string

    and the fixed widths are: 4, 5, 6, 6.
```

If a value exceeds this width, the last characters need to be cut off. So 
for example:

```
    124891, difference, 22.348, montreal
```

the strings that need to be printed ought to be:

```
    1248 diffe 22.348 montre
```

I am thinking I need to do something in the constructor that forces a 
string not to exceed a certain number of characters. I will probably 
cast the doubles and ints to a string, so I can enforce the maximum width 
requirements.

I don't know which method does this or if a string can be instantiated to 
behave taht way.  Using the formatter only helps with the 
fixed-with formatting for printing the string, but it does not actually 
chop characters that exceed the maximum length.

Comment: if ( ff.length()>7 ) ff = ff.substring(0,7);

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use this to cut off the non needed characters:

```
String.substring(0, maxLength);
```

Example:

```
String aString ="123456789";
String cutString = aString.substring(0, 4);
// Output is: "1234"
```

To ensure you are not getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when the input string is less than the expected length do the following instead:

```
int maxLength = (inputString.length() < MAX_CHAR)?inputString.length():MAX_CHAR;
inputString = inputString.substring(0, maxLength);
```

If you want your integers and doubles to have a certain length then I suggest you use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) to format your numbers instead of cutting off their string representation.

Comment: Hmm. It would be great if "Precision" works for String as well.

Comment: I think `inputString.substring(0, Math.min(MAX_CHAR, inputString.length()));` is much more readable.

Comment: or `inputString.substring(0, (inputString.length() > MAX_CHAR) ? MAX_CHAR : inputString.length())`

Comment: this coupled with the String.transform() function introduced in JDK 12 is the best :)

Comment: This answer may produce invalid string if it contains surrogate pairs.

Comment: Performance of @pvorb answer is good, because `String.substring()` implementation has a special check to return `this` if `beginIndex==0 && endIndex==value.length)`

Answer (score 194):

You can also use `String.format("%3.3s", "abcdefgh")`. The first digit is the minimum length (the string will be left padded if it's shorter), the second digit is the maxiumum length and the string will be truncated if it's longer. So

```
System.out.printf("'%3.3s' '%3.3s'", "abcdefgh", "a");
```

will produce

```
'abc' '  a'
```

(you can remove quotes, obviously).

Comment: use [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) as a more common approach

Comment: Whats String Syntax to get the last n character of a string?

Comment: Probably slower than `String::substring(0, max)` however.

Answer (score 37):

For readability, I prefer this:

```
if (inputString.length() > maxLength) {
    inputString = inputString.substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

over the accepted answer.

```
int maxLength = (inputString.length() < MAX_CHAR)?inputString.length():MAX_CHAR;
inputString = inputString.substring(0, maxLength);
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the Apache Commons `StringUtils.substring(String str, int start, int end)` static method, which is also null safe.

See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29

and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.1961

Comment: Even easier: use the [left method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#left-java.lang.String-int-).

Comment: Very excessive to add a library to truncate a string. Caution for this solution would be to only use this if you already are using commons

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve this easily using

```
    shortString = longString.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), MAX_LENGTH));
```

Answer (score 19):

If you just want a maximum length, use `StringUtils.left`! No `if` or `ternary ?:` needed.

```
int maxLength = 5;
StringUtils.left(string, maxLength);
```

Output:

```
      null -> null
        "" -> ""
       "a" -> "a"
"abcd1234" -> "abcd1"
```

[`Left` Documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#left-java.lang.String-int-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution may be `java.lang.String.format("%" + maxlength + "s", string).trim()`, like this:

```
int maxlength = 20;
String longString = "Any string you want which length is greather than 'maxlength'";
String shortString = "Anything short";
String resultForLong = java.lang.String.format("%" + maxlength + "s", longString).trim();
String resultForShort = java.lang.String.format("%" + maxlength + "s", shortString).trim();
System.out.println(resultForLong);
System.out.println(resultForShort);
```

ouput:

`Any string you want w`

`Anything short`

Comment: Using "%.20s" instead of "%20s" prevents the need for the trim

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should try not to modify the internal data representation for the purpose of creating the table. Whats the problem with String.format()? It will return you new string with required width.

Comment: Well, maybe I am using it wrong. but it does not actually change the length of my string. I have used the formatter with no effect. It does print stuff nicely, but it doesn't change string's lengths:
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();      //  Corresponding formats for declared members
        String hardCodedFormat =   "%5s%5s";     //  %20s  String  m_Project;
        String name = "mynameis";
        String name2 = "ted123";
        fmt.format(hardCodedFormat, name, name2);

        System.out.println(fmt);

Comment: @Flethuseo You should be able to truncate the strings. Try this:         System.err.format("%1$.5s", "A long string");