# Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces

Tags: java, string, formatting

I need to produce fixed length string to generate a character position based file. The missing characters must be filled with space character.

As an example, the field CITY has a fixed length of 15 characters. For the inputs "Chicago" and "Rio de Janeiro" the outputs are

```
"        Chicago"
" Rio de Janeiro"
```

.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Since Java 1.5 we can use the method [java.lang.String.format(String, Object...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and use printf like format.

The format string `"%1$15s"` do the job. Where `1$` indicates the argument index, `s` indicates that the argument is a String and `15` represents the minimal width of the String.
Putting it all together: `"%1$15s"`.

For a general method we have:

```
public static String fixedLengthString(String string, int length) {
    return String.format("%1$"+length+ "s", string);
}
```

Maybe someone can suggest another format string to fill the empty spaces with an specific character?

Comment: `Maybe someone can suggest another format string to fill the empty spaces with an specific character?` - take a look a the answer I gave.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html, `1$` represents the argument index and `15` the width

Comment: This will not limit the string to length 15. If it is longer, produced output will also be longer than 15

Comment: @misterti  a string.substring would limit it to 15 characters. Best regards

Comment: I should have mentioned that, yes. But the point of my comment was to warn about the possibility of longer output than desired, which could be a problem for fixed length fields

Comment: see [Limiting the number of characters in a string, and chopping off the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369708/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-string-and-chopping-off-the-rest) @jaksa
You can also use String.format("%3.3s", "abcdefgh"). The first digit is the minimum length (the string will be left padded if it's shorter), the second digit is the maxiumum length and the string will be truncated if it's longer. So

    System.out.printf("%3.3s%3.3s", "abcdefgh", "a");

will produce

    'abc  a'

Comment: @RafaelBorja For integer numbers you can fill an index-based reference with zeros (zero-padding) using the following format: `%1$06d` (where 6 is the total length of the number)

Comment: Doesnt work for me with character other than space. try it with '.'

Answer (score 68):

Utilize `String.format`'s padding with spaces and replace them with the desired char.

```
String toPad = "Apple";
String padded = String.format("%8s", toPad).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(padded);
```

Prints `000Apple`.

---

**Update** more performant version (since it does not rely on `String.format`), that has no problem with spaces (thx to Rafael Borja for the hint).

```
int width = 10;
char fill = '0';

String toPad = "New York";
String padded = new String(new char[width - toPad.length()]).replace('\0', fill) + toPad;
System.out.println(padded);
```

Prints `00New York`.

But a check needs to be added to prevent the attempt of creating a char array with negative length.

Comment: Updated code will works great. That what i expected @thanks mike

Answer (score 37):

This code will have exactly the given amount of characters; filled with spaces or truncated on the right side:

```
private String leftpad(String text, int length) {
    return String.format("%" + length + "." + length + "s", text);
}

private String rightpad(String text, int length) {
    return String.format("%-" + length + "." + length + "s", text);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
String.format("%15s",s) // pads left
String.format("%-15s",s) // pads right
```

Great summary [here](https://www.journaldev.com/17850/java-string-format#java-string-format-example)

Comment: Flipped. String.format("%-15s",s) // pads right. s="HAMBURGER" gives you "HAMBURGERbbbbbb", where "b" = space. The content at the link shows the example, String s1 = String.format("{%20s}", "Hello Format"); and claims output is {        Hello Format}, which I agree with. That's a pad left.

Comment: @SoftwareProphets Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

For right pad you need `String.format("%0$-15s", str)`

i.e. `-` sign will "right" pad and no `-` sign will "left" pad

See my example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Solution {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                String s1=sc.nextLine();
                
                
                Scanner line = new Scanner( s1);
                line=line.useDelimiter(" ");
               
                String language = line.next();
                int mark = line.nextInt();;
                
                System.out.printf("%s%03d\n",String.format("%0$-15s", language),mark);
                
            }
            System.out.println("================================");
 
    }
}
```

The input must be a string and a number

example input : Google 1

Answer (score 13):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String stringToPad = "10";
int maxPadLength = 10;
String paddingCharacter = " ";

StringUtils.leftPad(stringToPad, maxPadLength, paddingCharacter)
```

Way better than Guava imo. Never seen a single enterprise Java project that uses Guava but Apache String Utils is incredibly common.

Answer (score 12):

You can also write a simple method like below

```
public static String padString(String str, int leng) {
        for (int i = str.length(); i <= leng; i++)
            str += " ";
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely not the most performant answer. Since strings are immutable in Java you're essentially generating N new strings in memory with length equal to str.length+1 and thus is hugely wasteful. A much better solution would only perform one string concatenation regardless of input string length and utilize StringBuilder or some other more efficient way of string conatenation in the for loop.

Comment: @anon58192932 This does not seem to be the case since Java 9, https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280, https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9jep-280-string-concatenations-will-never-be-t .

Answer (score 11):

The [Guava Library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) has [Strings.padStart](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart-java.lang.String-int-char-) that does exactly what you want, along with many other useful utilities.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a neat trick:

```
// E.g pad("sss","00000000"); should deliver "00000sss".
public static String pad(String string, String pad) {
  /*
   * Add the pad to the left of string then take as many characters from the right 
   * that is the same length as the pad.
   * This would normally mean starting my substring at 
   * pad.length() + string.length() - pad.length() but obviously the pad.length()'s 
   * cancel.
   *
   * 00000000sss
   *    ^ ----- Cut before this character - pos = 8 + 3 - 8 = 3
   */
  return (pad + string).substring(string.length());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  try {
    System.out.println("Pad 'Hello' with '          ' produces: '"+pad("Hello","          ")+"'");
    // Prints: Pad 'Hello' with '          ' produces: '     Hello'
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code with tests cases ;) :

```
@Test
public void testNullStringShouldReturnStringWithSpaces() throws Exception {
    String fixedString = writeAtFixedLength(null, 5);
    assertEquals(fixedString, "     ");
}

@Test
public void testEmptyStringReturnStringWithSpaces() throws Exception {
    String fixedString = writeAtFixedLength("", 5);
    assertEquals(fixedString, "     ");
}

@Test
public void testShortString_ReturnSameStringPlusSpaces() throws Exception {
    String fixedString = writeAtFixedLength("aa", 5);
    assertEquals(fixedString, "aa   ");
}

@Test
public void testLongStringShouldBeCut() throws Exception {
    String fixedString = writeAtFixedLength("aaaaaaaaaa", 5);
    assertEquals(fixedString, "aaaaa");
}


private String writeAtFixedLength(String pString, int lenght) {
    if (pString != null && !pString.isEmpty()){
        return getStringAtFixedLength(pString, lenght);
    }else{
        return completeWithWhiteSpaces("", lenght);
    }
}

private String getStringAtFixedLength(String pString, int lenght) {
    if(lenght < pString.length()){
        return pString.substring(0, lenght);
    }else{
        return completeWithWhiteSpaces(pString, lenght - pString.length());
    }
}

private String completeWithWhiteSpaces(String pString, int lenght) {
    for (int i=0; i<lenght; i++)
        pString += " ";
    return pString;
}
```

I like TDD ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Apache common lang3 dependency's StringUtils exists to solve Left/Right Padding

**Apache.common.lang3** provides the `StringUtils` class where you can use the following method to left padding with your preferred character.

```
StringUtils.leftPad(final String str, final int size, final char padChar);
```

Here, This is a static method and the parameters

1. str  - string needs to be pad (can be null)
2. size - the size to pad to
3. padChar the character to pad with

We have additional methods in that StringUtils class as well.

1. rightPad
2. repeat
3. different join methods

I just add the Gradle dependency here for your reference.

```
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0

Please see all the utils methods of this class.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

## GUAVA Library Dependency

This is from jricher answer. The Guava Library has Strings.padStart that does exactly what you want, along with many other useful utilities.

Answer (score 1):

This code works great. [image: Expected output]

```
  String ItemNameSpacing = new String(new char[10 - masterPojos.get(i).getName().length()]).replace('\0', ' ');
  printData +=  masterPojos.get(i).getName()+ "" + ItemNameSpacing + ":   " + masterPojos.get(i).getItemQty() +" "+ masterPojos.get(i).getItemMeasure() + "\n";
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String padString(String word, int length) {
    String newWord = word;
    for(int count = word.length(); count < length; count++) {
        newWord = " " + newWord;
    }
    return newWord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple function works for me:

```
public static String leftPad(String string, int length, String pad) {
      return pad.repeat(length - string.length()) + string;
    }
```

Invocation:

```
String s = leftPad(myString, 10, "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int s;
            String s1 = sc.next();
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%-15s%03d\n", s1, x);
            // %-15s -->pads right,%15s-->pads left
        }
    }
}
```

Use `printf()` to simply format output without using any library.