# how to generate string with varying number of spaces OR how to add no of spaces after a string

Tags: java

I need help to generate empty string with particular no of spaces.

I tried this,

```
String opCode=  " ";

for(int l=0;l<opCodelen;l++)
{
    opCode+= " " ;   
}
//opCodelen will get change every time
```

This worked but I want better solution.becoz using this I will have to use multiple loops for multiple columns.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean multiple columns?

Comment: Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Or `String.format()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
    int opCodelen = 5;
    String opCode = String.format("%" + opCodelen + "s", "");
    System.out.println("[" + opCode + "]");
```

output

```
[     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (uglier but for many probably simpler) to solve it could be

- creating array of characters with same length as number of spaces you want to end up with,
- filling it with spaces
- and passing it as argument in `String` constructor.

Something like

```
char[] arr = new char[10]; // lets say length of string should be 10
Arrays.fill(arr, ' ');     // fill array with spaces
String mySpaceString = new String(arr);
System.out.println(">" + mySpaceString + "<");
```

output:

```
>          <
```