# Using String.format to align toString() statements and put commas within them

Tags: java, printf, tostring, string.format

So I have a program made up of four classes. A Boat superclass, SailBoat and PowerBoat subclasses, and a test program where I have an arrayList of different sail and powerboats.

I have a toString() method that looks like this in the SailBoat class, the PowerBoat has the same one excpet it replaces number of sails with engine size.

```
public String toString()
   {
      return super.toString() + " Number of Sails = " + numSails + " Price = " + calcPrice();
   }
```

In my test class, I have to print out the ArrayList of boats I have. Currently I am doing that like this:

```
for(Boat b: boats)
  {
     System.out.printf(b.toString());
     System.out.printf("\n");
  }
```

This returns my list of boats, but it isn't aligned at all and looks like this:

```
Color = blue Length = 22 Engine Size = 60 Price = 12800.0
Color = white Length = 20 Number Sails = 1 Price = 22000.0
Color = red Length = 42 Number Sails = 3 Price = 48000.0
Color = yellow Length = 35 Engine Size = 80 Price = 17100.0
Color = red Length = 50 Engine Size = 120 Price = 22400.0
Color = blue Length = 33 Number Sails = 2 Price = 37000.0
Color = white Length = 20 Engine Size = 10 Price = 11200.0
```

I would like it to look like (the * are supposed to represent padding or space holders):

```
Color = blue   Length = 22  Engine Size = *60  Price = $ 12,800.00
Color = white  Length = 20  Number Sails = *1  Price = $ 22,000.00
Color = red    Length = 42  Number Sails = *3  Price = $ 48,000.00
Color = yellow Length = 35  Engine Size = *80  Price = $ 17,100.00
Color = red    Length = 50  Engine Size = 120  Price = $ 22,400.00
Color = blue   Length = 33  Number Sails = *2  Price = $ 37,000.00
Color = white  Length = 20  Engine Size = *10  Price = $ 11,200.00
```

I know I'm to supposed to use String.format() on the to String methods, but all of the examples I see on the Oracle site and elsewhere don't make any sense to me and don't show to apply them to the toString methods. Some help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

```
String color1 = "yellow";
int length1 = 33;
String color2 = "red";
int length2 = 333;
System.out.println(String.format("Color = %-10s Length = %5d", color1, length1));
System.out.println(String.format("Color = %-10s Length = %5d", color2, length2));
```

Above is a minimal example you can try. All you need are placeholders of fixed length (which you can specify). And the presence or absence of the minus sign dictates that the text is left aligned or right aligned.

Comment: I should have mentioned, this is for a lab in one of my programming classes. I have the program working but for the format it says that a String.format statement needs to be applied to all toString methods. Is that what you did above, or does hat just create new attributes and apply it to them?

Comment: @AbbeyS In your `toString` method, just return `String.format("MyFormat", value1, value2, ...)`