# How to make inner divs of two unrelated outer divs equal in height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a translation/dictionary website where I have two columns, one contains a text and the other contains the translation/meaning in another language.

Here is a pen for what I achieved right now 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMVrvR?editors=0100

HTML

```
        <div class="chapter" style="direction: ltr;">
            <p class="">
                col#1
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id ="left" class="lines" style="height: 532px; margin-right: -17px;" tabindex="0">
            <div class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">1</span><span class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula</span>
            </div>
            <div  class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">2</span><span class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo </span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class=" index-no">3</span><span class="">parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class=" index-no">4</span><span class="">. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class=" index-no">5</span><span class="">Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class=" index-no">6</span><span class="">Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class=" index-no">7</span><span class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula </span>
            </div>
            <p class="blank-line"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="block" style="width: 600px; height: 686px; ">
    <div class="block-inner">
        <div class="chapter" style="direction: ltr;">
            <p class="">
                col#2
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id ="right" class="lines" style="height: 532px; margin-right: -17px;" tabindex="0">
            <div class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">1</span><span >Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <span class="index-no">2</span><span class=""> A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of </span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">3</span><span class="">packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her ho</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">4</span><span class="">the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" >
                <span class="index-no">5</span><span class=""> The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks </span>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <span class="index-no">6</span><span class="">the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <span class="index-no">7</span><span class="">A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of!</span>
            </div>
            <p class="blank-line"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see every column contains inner divs that contains text/translation.

What I need to do is:

make the height of every inner div in column#1 is equal to the corresponding inner div height in column#2, which means:

height of div#1 in col#1 =  height of div#1 in col#2

and
height of div#2 in col#1 =  height of div#2 in col#2
etc.

Please note:
- the text and translation created dynamically from the database so I can't know what is the size of the div.
-Sometimes the text height will be larger than translation height while other times the translation height is larger.
- I want to keep the scroll-bars in the 2 columns because I want to give users the ability to scroll in one column only or scroll the 2 columns synchronized with each other, so I think making the text and corresponding translation into one div will not work.
- there will be a +300 inner div/page so if you will use java-script/jquery to solve this , I hope it will be fast.

So what is the best way to make the corresponding div take the same height?

Comment: Probably you should add columns in a same row. I mean one div per ow with inner left / right divs

Comment: One thing I didn't quite like was your comment, and I quote "so if you will use java-script/jquery to solve this , I hope it will be fast.". In any case, I'll give you a lead, try it out yourself then come back with your own written code, even if it's a failed one, at least you attempted something. Here is one way of doing it. If the amount of the rows will always be even, make the id of each row in sequence for both columns the same so they correspond to each other, use javascript to get the biggest height for each corresponding row, then javascript css func to set the height for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGVGwj

```
// Create two arrays for the left element heights and the right element heights
var leftArray = [];
var rightArray = [];

// Get the height of each .line element and save it to the appropriate array
$('#left .line').each(function(i) {
  leftArray.push($(this).height());
});
$('#right .line').each(function(i) {
  rightArray.push($(this).height());
});

// For each element on the left, if its height is smaller than the
// corresponding element on the right, set its height via css to 
// equal the right-side element, and vice versa. Nothing to do if 
// the heights are equal.
for (var i = 0; i < leftArray.length; i++) {
  if (leftArray[i] < rightArray[i]) {
    $('#left .line').eq(i).css('height', rightArray[i])
  } else if (leftArray[i] > rightArray[i]) {
    $('#right .line').eq(i).css('height', leftArray[i])
  }
}
```

I think this will be fairly fast, at least faster than setting a height on every single element. There's absolutely some work to do for responsive or mobile environments, so this isn't an ideal scenario by any means, but hopefully this does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and fairly fast for the case of 2 columns. I did some changes to use for any number of columns and I thought using Reduce() function would be a nice idea, it works but become very slow, Can you help with the new code to make it faster or to suggest another way for doing that? 

This is the link for the new pen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzWorV?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below. I used flex instead.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .cell {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .header {
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <div class="header cell">Original</div>
 
 <div class="header cell">Translation</div>

  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula</div>

  <div class="cell">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,</div>
  
   <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula</div>

  <div class="cell">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,</div>
  
   <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula</div>

  <div class="cell">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but I need to have a scroll bar for every column

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```
function sameHeight(leftId,rightId){
    $('#'+ leftId + ' .line').each(function(i){
        var h = $(this).outerHeight(); // get height
        $(this).css('height', h); // set height to left
        $('#' + rightId + ' .line').eq(i).css('height', h); // set height to right
    });
}
sameHeight('left','right');
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through left and get the height of each element. I added an if statement to figure out which side is higher and then increase the height of the smaller one.

Best of luck with it!

```
var n = 1;
jQuery('#left .line').each(function(){
  var left_height = jQuery(this).height();
  var right_height = jQuery('#right .line:nth-of-type(n)').height();
  if(left_height > right_height){
    jQuery('#right .line:nth-of-type(n)').height(left_height);
  }
  if(right_height > left_height){
    jQuery(this).height(right_height);
  }
  n++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an incremental identical subclass to both the div elements whose height should correspond:
column1:

```
<div class="line ev1" ></div>
<div class="line ev2" ></div>
...
```

column2:

```
<div class="line ev1" ></div>
<div class="line ev2" ></div>
...
```

make a cicling trought jQuery for each line element and a subcicle on subclasses in order to get the tallest, than assign tallest height to the current subclass

```
var maxHeight = 0;
var c=0;

$(".line").each(function () {
 c++;

$(".ev"+c).each(function () { 
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
 })
    $(".ev"+c).height(maxHeight);
});
```

check my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wvfqgkk1/4/

Answer (score 0):

In css add a style

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and in JS calculate each line height from both side and set max height in relative small side line.

```
var leftLines = leftDiv.querySelectorAll('.line');
var rightLines = rightDiv.querySelectorAll('.line');
if(leftLines.length && leftLines.length == rightLines.length) {
  for(var i=0; i<leftLines.length; i++) {
    if(leftLines[i].offsetHeight >= rightLines[i].offsetHeight) {
      rightLines[i].style.height = leftLines[i].offsetHeight + 'px';
    } else {
      leftLines[i].style.height = rightLines[i].offsetHeight + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution can be adding white spaces in shorter string to make it equal in length to that of larger string.

```
String a="hello";             // smaller string 
String b="hello,hello...."   // larger string

public static String appendSpaces(String s1,String s2){

     if(s1.length() < s2.length()){
         int d=s2.length() - s1.length();
         s1=String.format("%1$"+d+ "s", s1);
     }
    else{
         int d=s1.length() - s2.length();
         s2=String.format("%1$"+d+ "s", s2);
    }
}
```

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces) for details of String.format.

Comment: justify reason before downvoting