# Java format string: left and right justification

Tags: java, string, format

I want to achieve that the currency symbol is fixed on a certain position (left justified) and the amount appears right justified. For example/clarification:

[image]

As it is a currency It needs to take into account the currency formatting. How can I achieve this? My current code is following:

```
String.format("%-30s%s","$",new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00").format(123478912345.34))
```

The code shown in [Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces) gets me far but as my font are not monospaced (same width for each character) I can not use the answers provided there to solve my issue.

Comment: As it is a currency, perhaps consider using a currency formatter :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces)

Comment: "but as my font are not monospaced" that suggests text is not printed in console (which usually uses monospaced font). In that case where exactly is it printed? Is it web-site, or pdf file? Maybe that output "technology" provides tools which are more suitable for this task.

Comment: @Pshemo After trying several options I went for the use of the template design options to solve this issue. I was hoping to use a form of string format to have a simpler solution but did not found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those stumbling on this question. I was unable to align the text in java (string format) due to the fact of the different wide in font (see comment Pshemo). Based on this I used the output technology to format the text.