# split string by fixed length and fill the free spaces with white spaces

Tags: java

I want to split strings into fixed-length, for example, split by 20 characters and if after splitting length is less than 20 characters, then fill the string with whitespace up to 20 characters.

```
public static List<String> splitEqually(String text, int size) {

    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>((text.length() + size - 1) / size);

    for (int start = 0; start < text.length(); start += size) {
        ret.add(text.substring(start, Math.min(text.length(), start + size)));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I used the above code to split by equal size.

Comment: Ok, and what is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces)

Comment: Only the last value might not be of the given size. Are you asking how to add spaces if last values length is less than `size`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will resolve your problem.

```
public static List<String> splitEqually(String text, int size) {

    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>((text.length() + size - 1) / size);
    StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
    for (int start = 0; start < text.length(); start += size) {
        String temp = text.substring(start, Math.min(text.length(), start + size));
        if (temp.length() == size) {
            ret.add(temp);
            System.out.println(temp.length());
        } else {
            int n = size - temp.length();
            str1.append(temp);
            for (int j =0 ; j< n ; j++){
                str1.append(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(str1.length());
            ret.add(str1.toString());
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: you don't have to check the size on every index. only the last substring would be small

Comment: alternatively, it is giving 35, 36 string length

Comment: it is not filling the whitespace if the length is less than

Comment: @boycod3 Now check . I have checked the length of spitted strings.

Comment: @sidgate As Start is incremented by size, we don't know when it will have the last check. So we need to check for the size in every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Only the last value might not be of the given size, so pad it with spaces if needed, *after* the loop.

```
public static List<String> splitFixedWidth(String text, int width) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>((text.length() + width - 1) / width);
    for (int start = 0; start < text.length(); start += width) {
        ret.add(text.substring(start, Math.min(text.length(), start + width)));
    }
    if (! ret.isEmpty()) {
        String lastValue = ret.get(ret.size() - 1);
        if (lastValue.length() < width) {
            lastValue += " ".repeat(width - lastValue.length());
            ret.set(ret.size() - 1, lastValue);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In Java versions below 11, use:

```
        if (lastValue.length() < width) {
            char[] buf = new char[width];
            lastValue.getChars(0, lastValue.length(), buf, 0);
            Arrays.fill(buf, lastValue.length(), width, ' ');
            ret.set(ret.size() - 1, new String(buf));
        }
```

Or shorter but less efficient:

```
        if (lastValue.length() < width) {
            ret.set(ret.size() - 1, String.format("%-" + width + "s", lastValue));
        }
```

Comment: the repeat is undefined, which version of java you're using?

Answer (score 0):

*with lambda*

```
String blanks20 = "                    ";
ArrayList<String> fixed20 = list.stream().collect( Collector.of( ArrayList::new,
    (l, s) -> {
        for(int i = 0; ; s = s.substring( 20 )) {
          l.add( (s + blanks20).substring( i, i + 20 ) );
          if( s.length() < 20 )
            break;
        } },
      (l, r) -> { l.addAll( r ); return( l ); } ) );
```