# java fixed width when outputting strings

Tags: java

Current uni student working on a task

I have the following string

```
System.out.println("product"+String.format("%30s", "price")+String.format("%30s", "sub total"));
```

which yields the following output

```
product           price         sub total
```

now when i add more strings on a new line - for example

```
System.out.println("products from database "+String.format("%30s", "quantity ")+String.format("%30s", "running total"));
```

my output is now

```
product           price         sub total
products from database         quantity         running total
```

I am looking for a way to always have the rows match up
Expected output:

```
product                        price           sub total
products from database         quantity        running total
```

these rows will be determined by user input and I would like them to all line up no matter how long they may be.

EDIT:
by looking at similar posts i changed my string to the following

System.out.println("Product"+String.format("%1$30s", "Price")+String.format("%1$30s", "sub total"));

When inserting larger texts it shifts everything over so it is still out of line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate fixed length Strings filled with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475388/generate-fixed-length-strings-filled-with-whitespaces)

Comment: 1) Find the largest header text.  In your example, it's "products from database".  2) Add margin amount. 3) Create formatter.  String formatter = "%" + maxLength + "s";  4) Format header text with formatter.