# Formatting Java output

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I've been having one heck of a time with this. I want to limit field width AND left justify these items. For example, in `%2$-13s`

I want to left justify this and limit the length to 13 characters. so if argument 2 is 15 characters long, it will only print 13 of those characters

```
result.setFormat("  %1$-25s %2$-13s %3$.5s %4$-7s %5$-9s %6$-10s %7$-5s "
                + "%8$-4s %9$-6s %10$-7s %11$-8s %12$-11s %13$-4s");
```

How do you do this?

Comment: What output are you currently getting, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: Well, Pshemo had the EXACT answer I needed but his post is deleted. So I would have accepted his answer. I also searched for quite some time to find this answer and couldn't find it. Thanks though

Comment: I noticed that main idea behind my answer was [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060643) in duplicate question so there is no need for repetition (also marking question as duplicate prevents others from posting new answers so letting only my answer stay wouldn't feel right).

Comment: Eh either way, I searched for about 30 mins and got your answer much faster - thanks for the help ^.^